# Azure pipeline NuGet restore fails to set MsBuild properties in csproj files

Tags: .net, nuget, azure-pipelines, csproj

I am trying to set up a pipeline for a C# project which uses the build configuration to decide which package to install. I can build just fine in Visual Studio, but using NuGetCommand@2 on Azure Pipelines fails to restore packages. It looks like when using that command, the property I created in the csproj file doesn't get set, so NuGet tries to find an invalid version of the package. Is there any way around this?

csproj:

```
...
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(Configuration.Contains('2020'))">
    <RevitVersion>2020</RevitVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autodesk.Revit.SDK" Version="$(RevitVersion).*" IncludeAssets="build; compile" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

pipeline:

```
...
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  projects: '**/*.csproj'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release 2020'

steps:
  - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
    displayName: 'Install NuGet'
    inputs:
        versionSpec: 
  - task: NuGetCommand@2
    displayName: 'Restore packages'
    inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
        configuration: $(buildConfiguration)
        feedsToUse: 'select'
        vstsFeed: '<private feed id>'
```

error:

`error MSB4018: System.ArgumentException: '.*' is not a valid version string.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It looks like when using that command, the property I created in the
> csproj file doesn't get set, so NuGet tries to find an invalid version
> of the package. Is there any way around this?

[Local Nuget Restore command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-restore) doesn't support `Configuration` switch.

[Online Nuget task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops) supports `Configuration` switch, however only the `nuget pack` command supports this switch. Online Nuget task has four commands: `Restore,Pack,Push,Custom`, the `Configuration` input is **only** valid for `nuget Pack`. That's why nuget pack ignores `configuration: $(buildConfiguration)` even if you doesn't receive warning/error when you edit the yaml pipeline.

**The Configuration input of that task is only for nuget pack!**

[image]

Similar discussions please check [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59166166/getting-nu1202-error-when-running-nuget-restore), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58109878/azure-devops-conditional-package-restoration), [link3](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/5895).

Here's suggestion from [Github/Nuget](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/6486#issuecomment-420395683). You can try using Nuget.config file and PAT to provide auth for `msbuild /t:restore`.